# A concise way to handle multiple checkboxes for a model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have two classes, Songs and Tags.The relationship is many-to-many. The problem I'm having is that when a user adds a new Song and checks off what Tags s/he wants and I call db.SaveChanges() in the controller, it adds duplicate Tags instead of adding only records to the join table. I've worked around this, but it's a hack. There's got to be a better solution?

Here's my code (abrreviated for clarity).

Song:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
public string SongTitle { get; set; }
```

Tag:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string TagName { get; set; }
public bool Selected { get; set; }
public List<Song> Songs { get; set; }
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    Song song = new Song();
    song.Tags = utilities.TagNames(_db, User.Identity.Name);
    return View(song);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Song song)
{
    //cycle thru the tags and grab ids of checked tags
    int tagCount = song.Tags.Count;
    List<int> tagIds = new List<int>();
    for (int i = tagCount - 1; i > -1; i--)
    {
        Tag tag = song.Tags[i];
        if (tag.Selected)
            tagIds.Add(tag.Id);
    }
    song.Tags = null;

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {                
        _db.Songs.Add(song);
        _db.SaveChanges();
        int songId = song.Id;

        string sql = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[TagSongs] (Tag_Id, Song_Id) VALUES ";
        foreach(int tagid in tagIds)
        {
            sql += "(" + tagid + "," + songId + "),";
        }
        //remove the last comma
        sql = sql.Substring(0, sql.Length - 1);
        _db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql);

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    SetCategoriesAndTags(song);
    return View(song);
}
```

View:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Tags.Count; i++)
{
    Tag t = Model.Tags[i];
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Tags[i].Selected)
    <label for="Tags_@i.ToString()__Selected">@t.TagName</label>
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Tags[i].Id)

    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Tags[i].TagName)
}
```

Comment: Are Song and Tag classes code first entities?

Comment: Also, do not use string concatenation for SQL queries or this will open you up to SQL Injection attack.

Comment: @ken4z Not sure what you mean by first entities. They're not derived classes. They're both DbSet<>'s in the DbContext.

Comment: In EntityFramework there is Code-First and DB-First. That's all I meant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, do not use string concatenation for SQL queries or this will open you up to SQL Injection attack.  This code should get you what you need.  Call it from your controller ActionMethod.

```
private void AddSongs(Song song, List<int> tagIds)
{
    _db.Songs.Add(song);
    foreach(var tagId in tagIds)
    {
        var tag = _db.Tags.SingleOrDefault(tagId);

        if(tag != null) song.Tags.Add(tag);
    }
    _db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this code is going to cause the same problem, I.E. it's going to create duplicate Tags. So say I have 2 tags, "Funny" and "Parody". The user checks them both of and adds the song. The next time a user goes to add a song, s/he'll be presented with 4 tags as options, 2 "Funny and 2 "Parody". As far as SQL injection, not sure how I'm vulnerable (other than polluting my join table with erroneous Tag_Id's), if the TagId isn't an integer, the model binding will fail.

Comment: You are correct that in this case you won't be attacked successfully, but it is a good idea to use best practices and they are easy to use.  If a developer comes in later to refactor this code and needs to add a string value for a where clause or something, they are more likely to update the existing implementation which could then open the window for attack.

Comment: It should work. I've used the construct for other many to many inserts.  (Note: I updated the code slightly so as to validate that the tagIds are valid, i.e. known tags).  Maybe the tagIds you were using were outside the range of ids already in the DB so it was inserting a new one.